# Can't load Select from Ajax with IE9

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have a select element that I fill with file names using ajax.

The HTML is:

```
<select id='load_dropdown' name=loads help_token="load_dropdown" title="">  
      <option value='' selected='selected'>LOAD</option>
</select>
```

The call to fill the element is:

```
 $('select#load_dropdown')  .load('getFiles.php', {list : 'LOAD'}); //fill the load drop down list
```

getFiles.php: is

```
$dir = $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "/xmls/";      // files are in xmls dir
if ($dirHandle = opendir($dir) ){  
}
else {
    echo ("<br />getFiles.php: $dir not found.");
    exit;
}

echo ("<option selected='selected' value=''><b> $list </b> </option>");   // first line of this drop down option
        while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dirHandle))) {
            if ($fileName == "." || $fileName == "..") {
                continue;
            }
            $fileNames[] = $fileName;       // collect file names
        } 

        sort($fileNames);
        foreach ($fileNames as $fileName) {
            $displayName = basename($fileName, '.xml');     // cut .xml at end
            echo ("<option value='$displayName'>" . $displayName . "</option>");  
        } 
    }
```

This works fine for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE10.  It doesn't work for IE9.

With IE9 the select element does not fill with the loaded information, though I can see that getFiles.php  call is returning the correct data. After the call the select element is

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on with IE9?

Thanks.

Comment: which jQuery version do you use?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to populate the select list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your jquery version ?
I've test this code with 1.9.1 and 1.10.2 :

**getFiles.php :**

```
<?php
//$dir = $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "/xmls/";      // files are in xmls dir
$dir = 'xmls/'; // for testing
if ($dirHandle = opendir($dir) ){  
} else {
    echo ("<br />getFiles.php: $dir not found.");
    exit;
}
echo ("<option selected='selected' value=''><b> $list </b> </option>");   // first line of this drop down option
while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dirHandle))) {
    if ($fileName == "." || $fileName == "..") {
        continue;
    }
    $fileNames[] = $fileName;       // collect file names
} 

sort($fileNames);
foreach ($fileNames as $fileName) {
    $displayName = basename($fileName, '.xml');     // cut .xml at end
    echo ("<option value='$displayName'>" . $displayName . "</option>");  
}
```

**get_files.html**

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<select id='load_dropdown' name=loads help_token="load_dropdown" title="">  
      <option value='LOAD' selected='selected'>LOAD</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('select#load_dropdown').load('getFiles.php', {list : 'LOAD'}); //fill the load drop down list
</script>
```

I have created a `xmls` folder in the root of the project with `file1.xml` and `file2.xml`.

It works on IE9 (ver 9.0.8112. update 9.0.24) (same result as other browsers). the listbox contain `file1` and `file2` :
[image: IE9 - load]

If you want to see the generated html, you juste have to click the refresh button (in the red square)

Hope it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for putting that code together.  I hope I gave you the points in time.  I was able to get your test to run on IE9, so I should be able to get mine to work now.  There's obviously nothing wrong with the basic approach.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The better way is to reference `div` and `span` elements:

```
<div id="select"><select id='load_dropdown' name=loads help_token="load_dropdown" title="">  
  <option value='' selected='selected'>LOAD</option>
</select>
</div>
```

-

```
$('#select #load_dropdown')  .load('getFiles.php', {list : 'LOAD'}); //fill the load drop down list
```